# Insert CSS Class inside a css class

Tags: css

What I want is like this code:

```css
class1:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #E0DADF;

    class2 {
        opacity:0.5;
    }
}
```

Is this even possible or there is any other way to make it like this?

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish by nesting? And no, plain CSS can't do this.

Comment: that when I hove class1, class2 to will also change.

Comment: @KevinSteveManingo - Is `class2` located within `class1` in the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.class1:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #E0DADF;
}

.class1:hover .class2 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Or use [a CSS preprocessor](http://css-tricks.com/musings-on-preprocessing/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In case of [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), or [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/), yeah this is possible. But if you want to nest the CSS Classes, you can do this way:

```
class1:hover{
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #E0DADF;
}

class1:hover class2{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something.
What you can also do, is make the element have multiple classes. For example,

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
<div class="class2"></div>
```

The first `div` element would also have the css styles of the second.